# Big data with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I have around 40K raster layers, each having an average size of 300 MB. I am trying to build the raster visualization system in which the user can select some parameters from different dropdown buttons and get the required layers. My question is how can I upload/manage the store/workspace so that the performance of the system will remain the same? What happens, if I upload all the rasters into only one workspace?

Is the performance of the system will slow down due to huge rasters?

Comment: do all your rasters cover the same area or do they form a mosaic?

Comment: Yes, All raster covers the same area

Comment: what distinguishes them - time, elevation some other attribute?

Comment: They may differ from the different time periods, crop type, Reflected Ceiling Plan. I am thinking of making different workspace according to the time period so that maybe 1000-5000 rasters for each workspace.

Comment: @ian, Do you have any suggestions? Please help me how can I arrange the files so that it won't affect the GeoServer performance.